# Iterating ordered dict items starting from specific key

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, slice

The question is styled in python 2.7 .

I'm using `OrderedDict` to store some items as follows:

```
d = OrderedDict(zip(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], range(4)))
```

(`d` equals to `{'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3}`)

Is there a way iterating dictionary `d`, starting from specific key?
For instance, I'd like to iterate `d` items starting from key `'b'`

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: There isn't any elegant way to do it. Why not just have an `if key != 'b': continue`?

Comment: do you want to loop back if you hit `d`? or do you just want to end after hitting `d`? (`d` being the key not the dictionary item :D)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. In real use case I'd like to eliminate multiple items, not just one.

Comment: I'd like to benefit slicing of lists while iterating d. For instance:  for k in d['c':]

Comment: So keep a list of keys you want to exclude, and `if key in excluded_keys: continue`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution that works for Python 2 and 3, using `itertools.dropwhile()`:

```
from __future__ import print_function

from collections import OrderedDict
from itertools import dropwhile

d = OrderedDict(zip(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], range(4)))

for k, v in dropwhile(lambda x: x[0] != 'b', d.items()):
    print(k, v)
```

Output:

```
b 1
c 2
d 3
```

Python 2, avoiding the creation of the key-value list with `.items()`::

```
for k, v in dropwhile(lambda x: x[0] != 'b', d.iteritems()):
    print(k, v)
```

#### Timing

```
%timeit
for each in d.items()[d.keys().index('b'):]:
    pass
The slowest run took 5.18 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.27 µs per loop

%%timeit
for each in islice(d.iteritems(), d.keys().index('b'), None):
    pass
The slowest run took 5.23 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.05 µs per loop

%%timeit
for k, v in dropwhile(lambda x: x[0] != 'b', d.iteritems()):
    pass
The slowest run took 4.92 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.23 µs per loop
```

Comment: Yes, that would be an improvement or Python 2.

Comment: I find this solution most aesthetic and elegant. Would you say it is the most efficient one as well compared to others suggested?

Comment: There is no copying if you use `iteritems()` in Python 2. Should have a good performance. `d.keys()` in Python 2 always creates a list (used in other solutions) . This is extra work.

Comment: Added some timings. This solutions is the fastest for this example.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate by looking up the value of `b` by using `items()` and slicing off where you need to be. Replace `d.keys().index('b')` if you have your own way of knowing where you want to start.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = OrderedDict(zip(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], range(4)))

for each in d.items()[d.keys().index('b'):]:
    print(each)
```

Using `items()` allow you to get the key and value off like normally.

Comment: I know and you know I don't feel right answering Python 2 questions, but eh. Since op `The question is styled in python 2.7 .`

Comment: Ah, didn't see that. Carry on ;D

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't this copy the entire dictionary? Better to use `iteritems()`?

Comment: @jpp `iteritems()` would not work since generators do not have a `__getitem__` call which doesn't allow slicing, which is what OP kinda wants. Hence Coldspeed's original (deleted) comment pointing out that this doesn't work in Py3 because in Py3 `items()` became `iteritems()`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me this is one option if you don't want to index a list of tuples:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from itertools import islice

d = OrderedDict(zip(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], range(4)))

for each in islice(d.iteritems(), d.keys().index('b'), None):
    print(each)
```

Answer (score -1):

Would this work?

```
for x in list(a.keys())[a.index(my_key):]:
    print(a[x])
```

where `my_key` is the key you want to start from